# How can spring convert strings to objects with no property editor implemented?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have implemented a REST API using spring boot. And in one of my controllers I was using ids to fetch objects like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    final User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In a lot of places I was calling find by id in controllers to get an object from its id. Then I saw spring PropertyEditors which will make it easier to pass objects between HTML and java code. So I implemented a property editor like below

```
@Component
public class UserPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        final User user = (User) getValue();
        if (user == null) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return user.getId().toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(text)) {
            setValue(userService.findById(Long.valueOf(text)));
        }
        else {
            setValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

After adding that, I changed my controller parameter
    getUser(@PathVariable("id") User user) and no need to call the findById method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So instead of the passing a Long then use userService.findById(Long), spring automatically instantiates the user object for me. I executed the application using mvn spring-boot:run. The tested the user endpoint and it worked as expected. When I do a GET to /api/v1/users/1, I get the user object. I thought it was the PropertyEditor doing that, so out of curiosity I deleted my property editor without modify my controller and tried the application again. Surprisingly it still worked. I just want to understand what is happening here. Is there a spring concept that says it can convert @PathVariable("id") to the target object automatically?

Comment: You're wanting the Spring `ConversionService`. Keep in mind that Spring Data offers something even more magical--`DomainClassConverter`. If you have a `CrudRepository<User, Long>`, then your `@PathVariable User id` will just work out of the box.